# Visual Web Developer Express DataClasses.dbml error "The operation could not be completed. The parameter is incorrect."

Tags: asp.net, visual-web-developer

The only thing I've found in searching this link
**http://forums.asp.net/t/1298084.aspx/1**
which unfortunately concerns VS 2008, and I am working in Visual Web Developer.

If anyone has seen this error before I'd appreciate any insight.

I've tried closing and reopening the project, as well as checking the compiler errors.

EDIT - I don't understand why this post is getting downvoted, if it's because I've been stupid about something then at least enlighten me to how I'm being stupid so I can learn.

I've tried editing the DataClasses.designer.cs but as I expected that hasn't had any effect. I've checked the Dataclasses.dbml in other projects and they still open correctly, but in both my development copy and backup copies (backups of the live and the old dev) for this project it doesn't open.

Comment: People are downvoting it because you haven't provided context, code or a sufficient explanation.

Comment: There's no code related to the problem as far as I'm aware. The context is your standard run of the mill C#/Linq website. I try to open the Dataclasses.dbml file and I get the error message listed in the subject. I'm not sure how much more I can clarify this. I guess the only path left to me is to do a side-by-side comparison of a file that works and a file that doesn't, but I don't think that will reveal the source of the problem, which I suspect is some kind of webconfig or global file setting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the DBML file and recreating it?  I've seen where the database mappings can get corrupt and usually just recreating it has worked for me in the past.

Comment: I'm hesitant to try this solution as this is a project I've inherited and I'm just adding on to it, it's possible that the original programmer had some custom code in there that I'm not aware of. I have a backup though so I will look into trying this solution, thank you.